# Spark Standalone Cluster not working well with Client deploy mode

Tags: apache-spark, deployment, cluster-computing, mode

I created a spark cluster with three nodes, one is for the master, and the other two are worker nodes. I can see the two workers on Spark master UI.

I created a sample project with a "WordCount" Scala program, it is very easy, just read file and count times of word occurrence.

I made a spark submit with deploy mode "Client" on master machine

> *./bin/spark-submit --class WordCount --master master-host:7077 --deploy-mode Client*

The "WordCount" got executed successfully. **BUT**, it is just executed on master only, and also the driver or app cannot be seen on Spark master UI. 
In my thought, it will be executed on the cluster(tasks distributed to executors on workers node), and the app can be viewed on spark master UI.

I did some research or even reading Spark Core source code, but no luck.
Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using your master's machine for a worker as well? Otherwise, how do you know that it's running on the master machine? Also, which machine are you running spark-submit from? Last: are you sure your `main` method isn't creating spark context in a conflicting way?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am running ./bin/spark-submit... on master node.   I did not use master as worker.  I am not sure what your mean of "creating spark context in a conflicting way"

Comment: I mean that your spark context in the application code could be being created with config pointing it to `local` as master...

Comment: oh, got your point. I sent conf with spark:// master-host:7077. I was expecting the driver could distribute rdd map and reduce to work node, but seems it does not. To be honest, I am not fully sure if worker has been invoked, because it is not shown on Spark master UI.

Comment: I got the reason of my issue, it is because my hdfs has some problem, my file in hdfs does not got picked up well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your spark submit deploy mode as cluster, default is client which in turn will execute the spark job only in the master node

```
./bin/spark-submit --class WordCount --master master-host:7077 --deploy-mode cluster
```

Please refer the official spark documentation for further details

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html